# How do I adjust the spacing around the sides of list items in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I have a list of things like this:

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
     <li><item 1/li>
     <li>item 2</li>
 </ul>
```

However, the sides of this keep stretching to the very end of the page. How could I add some kind of padding around the edges like in the api example found here:  http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-nested.html

I know I can add some css that would ajust the margin, However I don't want this to be added when viewing the page on a cell phone
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can go with a standard solution:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-inset="true">
    <li><item 1/li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Or you can go all commando like this:

```
.ui-listview {
    margin: 20px !important;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/2PhBQ/

Comment: I had this but I didn't really like the curved edges. Thanks for the thought though

Comment: You are fast but look at the rest of my answer.

Comment: thanks, that works great. However, if I adjust the size of my browser, the margin is always there. On the api site that I gave up top, the spacing disappears when making the screen smaller. I don't want the spacing to be there if I view this on an iphone. Any ideas?

Comment: That is the point of margin, to stay there. It can be margin or padding on content div. I can make it disappear on a smaller device, you only need to tell me at what screen size do you want it to disappear?

Comment: I got it. I ended up making my max-width for my entire list to be 1300px. Then I added "margin: auto" to always keep the margins equal on both sides. That worked like a charm